# When I cannot use ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

According to best practices it is recommended to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` with `async/await` keywords if you can:

```
await Task.Run(RunSomethingAsync).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Can you please give me an example of a situation when I cannot use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: It is when you need the continuation to return on the context it originated from, so most canonically the UI context.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth right, now it makes perfect sense to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *"cannot"* use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when you actually care about the synchronization context you're in. For example, imagine the following in a GUI application:

```
public async void SomeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await SomeAsyncOperation().ConfigureAwait(false);
    textBox.Text = result;
}
```

When you return from `ConfigureAwait`, you wont be back on the UI thread. This will cause an `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [source: Asynchronous .NET Client Libraries for Your HTTP API and Awareness of async/await's Bad Effects](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronousnet-client-libraries-for-your-http-api-and-awareness-of-async-await-s-bad-effects):

> When you are awaiting on a method with await keyword, compiler
>   generates bunch of code in behalf of you. One of the purposes of this
>   action is to handle synchronization with the UI (or main) thread. The key
>   component of this feature is the `SynchronizationContext.Current` which
>   gets the synchronization context for the current thread.
>   `SynchronizationContext.Current` is populated depending on the
>   environment you are in. The `GetAwaiter` method of Task looks up for
>   `SynchronizationContext.Current`. If current synchronization context is
>   not null, the continuation that gets passed to that awaiter will get
>   posted back to that synchronization context.
>
> When consuming a method, which uses the new asynchronous language
>   features, in a blocking fashion, you will end up with a deadlock if
>   you have an available SynchronizationContext. When you are consuming
>   such methods in a blocking fashion (waiting on the Task with Wait
>   method or taking the result directly from the Result property of the
>   Task), you will block the main thread at the same time. When
>   eventually the Task completes inside that method in the threadpool, it
>   is going to invoke the continuation to post back to the main thread
>   because `SynchronizationContext.Current` is available and captured. But
>   there is a problem here: the UI thread is blocked and you have a
>   deadlock!